# react component state changed only once

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have two components `<App />` and `<CompA/>`

The task I want to accomplish is,

I have a **state** in `<App/>` and an **input** field `<CompA/>` and I want to change the state of `<App/>` by changing the **input** in `<CompA/>`

**App.js**

```
export default function App() {
  const [containers, setContainers] = useState({
    invoiceData: null,
    containers: [
      { id: "09d4ba8a-30f1-4bf5-8b9f-ca45c497039a", containerNum: "" }
    ]
  });

  const changeContainerNum = (e, index) => {
    let current = containers;
    current.containers[index].containerNum = e.target.value;

    // current variable change on every function call
    console.log("local variable", current);
    setContainers(current);
  };
  // but state only change once
  console.log("////state", containers);

  return (
    <div>
      {containers.containers.map((container, index) => (
        <CompA
          key={container.id}
          index={index}
          changeContainerNum={changeContainerNum}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

**CompA.js**

```
function CompA({ changeContainerNum, index }) {
  const [containerNumber, setContainerNumber] = useState("");

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        placeholder="Container Number..."
        value={containerNumber}
        onChange={(e) => {
          changeContainerNum(e, index);
          setContainerNumber(e.target.value.toUpperCase());
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default CompA;
```

I want to change the **containerNum** property of `containers` state,

**The Issue is**

when the onChange event gets triggered the `changeContainerNum(e, index)` the code works fine in this function but when I assign the new changed value to the state then it updates the state only once

```
onChange={(e) => {
          // 
          changeContainerNum(e, index);
          setContainerNumber(e.target.value.toUpperCase());

        }}
```

**How can I update the state on every onChange event.**
It will be helpful to update [code here](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-surf-ukl8jf?file=/src/CompA.js:0-449)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not mutate a state variable, you must instead create a new reference :

```js
const changeContainerNum = (e, index) => {
  const containerNum = e.target.value;

  setContainers(({invoiceData, containers})=> ({
    invoiceData,
    containers: containers.map((container, idx) => 
      idx === index ? {...container, containerNum} : container
    )
  }));
};
```

Comment: Thanks, it is working, it would be more helpful if you explained to me about "reference".

Comment: What I mean by 'reference', is just that you need to pass a new array. React uses `===` to do comparison, so if you update the existing array, React will not detect any change, you must create a new array (using the `map` function in my example) so that React can detect the change